# Why won't this code search if wordToList[0] is a vowel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def ecrypt(w):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    wordToList = list(w)
    if (wordToList[0] == vowels):
        w = w + "-way"
    return w
```

In this code, i'm trying to figure out if the first item in wordToList is a vowel.

Comment: Did you mean: `if wordToList[0] in vowels:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` is an equality operator. Usually used to compare objects.

To check if an item is present in a list, use the `in` keyword.

Example:

```
if (word_to_list[0] in vowels):
    print('Found a vowel')
```